# Center of mass of a wire frame?

Tags: geometry

I have this question on centers of mass which I'm trying to solve, I managed to get a value for both $x$ and $y$ of $(0.3,0.4)$ but apparently it's $0.5$ from $AD$?

> [image]
>
> A uniform square frame $ABCD$ has sides of length $0.6 \text{ m}$. The side $AD$ is removed from the frame, and the open frame $ABCD$ is attached at $A$ to a fixed point (see diagram).
>
> (i) Calculate the distance of the center of mass of the open frame from $A$.

Comment: I did the same computation and got $(0.4,0.3)$

Comment: If $x$-direction is pointing left and $y$-axis is pointing upwards, then $$(x,y) = (0.4,-0.3) = \frac13\big( (0.3,0) + (0.6, -0.3) + (0.3, -0.6)\big)$$ from $A$. In this sort of calculation of $CM$, you can replace each line segment by a single point mass (mass equal to that of segment) at the $CM$ of that segment (in this case, the mid-points).

Comment: Note that the question (as you entered it) asks for the distance from $A$, not $\overline{AD}$.  That distance is $\sqrt{0.3^2+0.4^2} = 0.5$.  Maybe that's the confusion?

Comment: @Brian I see! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was

> (i) Calculate the distance of the center of mass of the open frame from A.

It's asking for the point-to-point distance from $A$, not the distance
from the segment $\overline{AD}$.

The center of mass is indeed at the coordinates $M=(0.4,0.3)$ 
as you computed, relative to the corner $D$
(letting the first coordinate be increasing to the right and the
second coordinate be increasing upward).

Note that this puts $A=(0,0.6)$ and the center of mass $M$ at two
diagonally opposite corners of a $0.4\times0.3$ rectangle.
The length of the diagonal of this rectangle is

$$|AM| = \sqrt{0.4^2 + 0.3^2} = 0.5.$$

Answer (score 2):

Your center of mass as measured from frame $AD$ is 
\begin{align}
\bar{x} &=\frac{\ell_{AB}x_{AB}+\ell_{BC}x_{BC}+\ell_{CD}x_{CD}}{\ell_{AB}+\ell_{BC}+\ell_{CD}} \\
&= \frac{(0.6)(0.3)+(0.6)(0.6)+(0.6)(0.3)}{0.6+0.6+0.6} \\
&= \boxed{0.4 \text{ m}}
\end{align}